# having trouble converting SELECT results correctly

Tags: php

Not sure if this should be in PHP or MySQL.

I have this query:

```
SELECT 
  product.*, 
  company.company-name 
FROM 
  products 
INNER JOIN 
  company ON products.company-id=company.id 
ORDER BY 
  company.company-name, 
  product.model
```

which I am outputting using this:

```
$group = array();
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $group[ $row['company-name'] ][] = $row;
}

foreach ($group as $company-name => $models) {
  foreach ($models as $model) {
    echo "Product Name: $model[model-name]";
    echo "Color: $model[color]";
    echo "Core Company: $model[core-company-id]"; // this is the line I am trying to fix
}
```

Obviously in my output above if I output $model[core-company-id] it is only going to be the number. I want the corresponding company from the 'company' table (core-company-id = the correct company.company-name / company.id) to be in its place.

I cant figure out how to do it. Can I adjust my original SELECT query/result somehow, do I need an extra query, or can I modify the php output somehow to fix this?

EDIT: I should add, the Core Company name will be different from the $company-name I am retrieving in the initial SELECT. That company is the product company name, but the maker of the 'core' will be a different company most times
For example, if core-company-id is 20, I want whichever company.company-name has a company.id of 20 to be put there

Thanks for any help.

**EDIT 2: Bear with me while I add table data etc. Sorry for not explaining this very well, I've found it difficult to put into words.**

EDIT 3: More information.

I have two tables:

Table 'Product' contains: id, main-company-id, model-name, color, core-company-id

Table 'Company contains: id, company-name

My output currently looks like this:

```
COMPANY NAME (comes from company.company-id)
Product 1 Name: Item name
Color: Blue
Core Company: 27 (comes from product.core-company-id)

Product 2 Name: Item 2 name
Color: Blue
Core Company: 35 (comes from product.core-company-id)

COMPANY NAME
Product 1 Name Item 1 Name
Color: Green
Core company: 27 (comes from product.core-company-id)
```

Having a hard time posting the output example correctly. Ugh. Not doing so good am I?

Comment: And what output do You expect?

Comment: "Core Company:" needs to be the company name that corresponds with product.core-company-id ---> company.id

Comment: You can edit that query, and you do not need an extra query. However I do not understand how this does qualify as a question here on SO. Try with SQLFiddle first.

Answer (score 1):

That should work:

```
foreach ($group as $company-name => $models) {
  foreach ($models as $model) {
    echo "Product Name: $model[model-name]";
    echo "Color: $model[color]";
    echo "Core Company: " . $company-name; // this is the line
  }
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the response, I'm stupid and didn't include some important information though, edit is above.

Comment: If I understood correctly - my response will still work. if not - please provide DB structure for both tables and sample data would help.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:  I just noticed in the SELECT and ORDER you are calling the table 'product' (singular) but in the FROM and JOIN you have 'products' (plural) - that would explain why you're not getting the result you expect!

It looks like you're not retrieving the value you want (core-company-id) with your select, or maybe it's in product but it's not clear to me where 'core-company-id' should come from.
Assuming it's a column in company table, this should work:

```
SELECT 
  product.*, 
  company.company-name 
  company.core-company-id
FROM 
  products 
INNER JOIN 
  company ON products.company-id=company.id 
ORDER BY 
  company.company-name, 
  product.model
```

you could always see what your array has with [print_r](http://www.php.net/print_r) and make sure the core-company-id is present;

```
print_r($group);  ## new line for testing here
foreach ($group as $company-name => $models) {
```

Edit: From reading your edits it sounds as if you may want to join the same table twice, which you can do, but it's still not clear to me where is core-company-id coming from.

Comment: Sorry, yeah, it appears I'm not retrieving core-company-id at all. core-company-id comes from the product table.

Comment: wait of course, I am retrieving it with "SELECT product.*" hmm

Comment: And thanks for your answer, am in the process of working on it. Appreciate everyone's responses.

Comment: Hi John - in the SELECT you have the table as 'product' singular but in the JOINs it's 'producs' plural - so you're not really selecting it!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe You need something like:

```
SELECT
  field1, 
  field2,
  company.company-id AS com_company-id
  company.company-name AS another_field
FROM table
...
product.company-id AS pro_company-id
...
```

Then You can use `another_field` in Your PHP code the same way as You use the `field1`.

As stated at [13.2.8. SELECT Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) "A select_expr can be given an alias using AS alias_name." You can set an expression and rename the field to some name that would be easy to access using PHP later. Such as `$model[another_field]`, `$model[com_company-id]`, `$model[pro_company-id]`.

If You have **the same field names in different tables** You can make aliases with `AS` and use them in Your SQL query as well (on `JOIN`s etc.).

If You need to get some `company_names` instead of `company_ids` You can use brackets `()` to create **SQL subqueries**. For example, to get a company name instead of "27", "35", etc.

Then there should be something like:

```
SELECT ... FROM ...
(
SELECT Company.company-name FROM Company
INNER JOIN Product
WHERE Company.id = Product.core-company-id
) AS company_name;
```

Using a Subquery to get the company name and access that as `$model[company_name]` in Your PHP code.

**Update**

Just noted, that You are messing up with "product" and "productS".

Maybe Your query should be like that:

```
SELECT 
  products.*, -- You have product.* here
  company.company-name 
FROM 
  products 
INNER JOIN 
  company ON products.company-id=company.id 
ORDER BY 
  company.company-name, 
  products.model -- You have product.model here
```

In that case, maybe, You will be able to select`$model[core-company-id]` as You did it earlier in PHP code.

Comment: Working to try and figure this out - I thank you for the effort in answering. Still working at getting it working using this...give me some time :)